# CSS - center element between the empty space?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the text(Tickle) vertically between the empty space that have left, Can you suggest me something that I should do in case.

The "show" Button should always stay in bottom.

And the text(Tickle) should be between "Search" button and the "Show" button.

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.level-buttons {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.level-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.search-button {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#search-button {
    padding: 10px 40%;
}

.show-button {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#show-button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    padding: 10px 40%;
}

.word {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.word-text {
    color: rgb(0, 94, 0);
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/semantic.min.css">
    <title>Learn Vocabulary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="level-buttons">
        <button onclick="changeLevel(1)" class="level-button ui active basic button level-1-button">L1</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(2)" class="level-button ui basic button level-2-button">L2</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(3)" class="level-button ui basic button level-3-button">L3</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(4)" class="level-button ui basic button level-4-button">L4</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(5)" class="level-button ui basic button level-5-button">L5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="search-button">
        <button class="ui basic purple button" id="search-button">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="word">
        <span class="word-text">Tickle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="show-button">
        <button class="ui black basic button" id="show-button">Show</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not have Computer Science background, this small app is intended for mobile. I appreciate your any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To **achieve** this **update** your **HTML** with following code

```
<div class="flex-box">
      <div>
        <div class="level-buttons">
          <button onclick="changeLevel(1)" class="level-button ui active basic button level-1-button">L1</button>
          <button onclick="changeLevel(2)" class="level-button ui basic button level-2-button">L2</button>
          <button onclick="changeLevel(3)" class="level-button ui basic button level-3-button">L3</button>
          <button onclick="changeLevel(4)" class="level-button ui basic button level-4-button">L4</button>
          <button onclick="changeLevel(5)" class="level-button ui basic button level-5-button">L5</button>
      </div>
      <div class="search-button">
          <button class="ui basic purple button" id="search-button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="word">
        <span class="word-text">Tickle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="show-button">
        <button class="ui black basic button" id="show-button">Show</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and your **CSS** with following

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.level-buttons {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.level-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.search-button {
  margin: 20px ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#search-button {
  padding: 10px 40%;
}

.show-button {
  margin: 20px ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#show-button {
  padding: 10px 40%;
}

.word {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.word-text {
  color: rgb(0, 94, 0);
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.level-buttons {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.level-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.search-button {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#search-button {
    padding: 10px 40%;
}

.show-button {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#show-button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    padding: 10px 40%;
}

.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  color: rgb(0, 94, 0);
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/semantic.min.css">
    <title>Learn Vocabulary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="level-buttons">
        <button onclick="changeLevel(1)" class="level-button ui active basic button level-1-button">L1</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(2)" class="level-button ui basic button level-2-button">L2</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(3)" class="level-button ui basic button level-3-button">L3</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(4)" class="level-button ui basic button level-4-button">L4</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(5)" class="level-button ui basic button level-5-button">L5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="search-button">
        <button class="ui basic purple button" id="search-button">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="center-screen">
      <section>
        <div>Tickle</div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="show-button">
        <button class="ui black basic button" id="show-button">Show</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Helpful but That not exactly what I want, it is in middle of the screen not in between those two buttons

Comment: The "Run Code Snippet" is messing it up. See if the result in "Full Page" is the one you want. I have updated the answer with result image.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your `.word` class

```
.word {
margin-top:50%;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
Try out this solution!
```

Wrap them in a new div and make it as flex-box.
Refactor some of the duplicate code just like bellow.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.level-buttons {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.level-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.button {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#show-button, #search-button {
    position:absolute;
    padding: 10px 40%;
}

.word {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.word-text {
    color: rgb(0, 94, 0);
    font-size: 32px;
}
.control-button {
display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/semantic.min.css">
    <title>Learn Vocabulary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="level-buttons">
        <button onclick="changeLevel(1)" class="level-button ui active basic button level-1-button">L1</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(2)" class="level-button ui basic button level-2-button">L2</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(3)" class="level-button ui basic button level-3-button">L3</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(4)" class="level-button ui basic button level-4-button">L4</button>
        <button onclick="changeLevel(5)" class="level-button ui basic button level-5-button">L5</button>
    </div>
<div class="control-button">
    <div class="button">
        <button class="ui basic purple button" id="search-button">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="word">
        <span class="word-text">Tickle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="ui black basic button" id="show-button">Show</button>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="/js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```